# How to utilize POWERVR™ SGX Series5 GPU from iPhone OS 4.0?

Tags: iphone

POWERVR™ SGX Series5 GPU is embedded in Apple iPhone and I wonder how to utilize it (i.e. use it as low power GP-GPU) from iPhone OS 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the GPU using OpenG ES 2.0, this is a shader based API and most GPGPU tutorials will map directly to GLSL.